# Defining multiple modules at once in the build definition

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a build setup where I have multiple groups of dependent modules. I wrote a function which produces one group of modules:

```
def group(id: String) = {
  val module1 = project.in(s"core/$id")...
  val module2 = project.in(s"impl/$id").dependsOn(module1)...
  (module1, module2)
}
```

I would now like to declare them:

```
val (core2014, impl2014) = group("2014")
```

This does not appear to work in `build.sbt`:

```
Pattern matching in val statements is not supported
```

I tried moving it into `project/build.scala`, where it gets compiled fine, but the modules don't appear in the SBT prompt. (That is, typing `core2014/compile` gives `not a valid key`.)

Is there any way I can add modules to the build "manually", instead of relying on the autodetection of SBT?

Comment: "def project: Project
Creates a new Project. This is a macro that expects to be assigned directly to a val. The name of the val is used as the project ID and the name of the base directory of the project."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess the answer is "no" for `build.sbt`.

But you can redefine [`projects`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v0.13.8/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Build.scala#L13) in your `project/Build.scala`

Comment: Not very satisfactory, but indeed, overriding `projects` seems like the way to go.